# How do I make a picture the full size of a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

[image]

I'm adding an `ImageIcon` to my `JButton` but the size of the Image is off. I want the Image to take up the full size of the `JButton` not only part, how do I make this happen? I attached an image of what is happening.

```
start = new JButton("Start Menu");
start.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Bobby\\Desktop\\Ocean.jpg");
int scale = 1; 
int width = ii.getIconWidth();
int newWidth = width / scale;
start.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
          java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
```

Comment: Start with the [setMargin](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin-java.awt.Insets-) method which JButton inherits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is restricted to only a portion of the `JButton` by default as it has both text and an icon to display

By overlaying the text on top of the image, the icon will grow to fill more of the button. This can be done by setting the vertical and horizontal preferences for the text placement:

```
start.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
start.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
```

At this point your image will cover most of the `JButton` but there will be a potentially unwanted portion of the `JButton` still visible around the border. This is due to the margin which is restricting further growth of the icon

By setting the margin to 0 with `start.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));`

The button should look similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Good looks brother! This did what I wanted and more!!

Answer (score 0):

I always keep my own Images class in my applications, this is possibly my most used method.

```
public static ImageIcon resizeImageIcon(ImageIcon ii, int width, int height){
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    return imageIcon;
}
```

this will re-size any existing ImageIcon.

I do also suggest that you use a JLabel that can be clicked. This is mostly to avoid the strange button border. In the case that you'd like this I've provide my own class that handles this as well.

```
import java.awt.Cursor;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class FClickLabel extends JLabel {

    public FClickLabel(ImageIcon on, ImageIcon off, ImageIcon press){
        this.setIcon(off);
        this.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        this.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                setIcon(on);
            }

            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                setIcon(off);
            }

            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                setIcon(press);
            }

            public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                setIcon(off);
            }

            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                clickAction();
            }
        });
    }

    public FClickLabel(String text, ImageIcon on, ImageIcon off, ImageIcon press){
        this.setIcon(off);
        this.setText(text);
        this.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        this.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                setIcon(on);
            }

            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                setIcon(off);
            }

            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                setIcon(press);
            }

            public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                setIcon(off);
            }

            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                clickAction();
            }
        });
    }

    public void clickAction() {

    }

}
```

If you only want the one image, you can simply provide it 3 times or remove the code that changes it and edit the constructor. when constructing the FClickLabel you can override the clickAction() like this example which I use for my application exit buttons:

```
FClickLabel exButton = new FClickLabel(Images.resizeImageIcon(Images.exitOn, 24, 24)
                ,Images.resizeImageIcon(Images.exitOff, 24, 24)
                ,Images.resizeImageIcon(Images.exitPress, 24, 24)){
            @Override
            public void clickAction(){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        };
```